# Remote connect local application -> MySql server. SSH C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, ssh, local

I'm in the folowing scenario:

I have a local application in WPF C# and I want a centralized database on a server (Webhotel). Security is not a critical matter at this point and there will only be one or two instances of the client application. It's not my own server so I don't have control over the server settings. I do, however, have access to a SSH account on the webhotell. I Use VS2012.

My question is:

How do I connect to the  MySql database and use it's data using "best practice" or any alternative. Upsides/downsides.

Also, if you do suggest using SSH, I whould realy appriciate code examples or links to tutorials.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Finding out a tutorial on MySQL and C# is [pretty easy](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+mysql+tutorial&oq=c%23+mysql+tutor&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i58j0l4.8866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Can you connect to SQL from SSH? Have you tried that in Console?